# how restore a database to a new machine in Stardog

Tags: stardog

I am trying to restore a database to a new machine in Stardog 2.1.3, but I get this error:

```
   Guice provision errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.io.IOException: Unable to create directory /home/**user-on-old-machine**/stardog-2.1.3/TEST
  at com.complexible.stardog.index.disk.ConcurrentDiskIndexLoader.<init>(ConcurrentDiskIndexLoader.java:33)
  while locating com.complexible.stardog.index.IndexBulkLoader annotated with interface com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted
```

It cannot create the restored database directory in stardog home directory on the new machine, however, it can create new databases with $stardog-admin db create -n NEW-DB.

I also tried on Windows machine. Same problem but different error which I don't have access to right now.

Comment: why not just create that directory?

Comment: Then I need to create a new user with the same name as the user on the old machine. It does not seem reasonable to create a user only for restoring a backup.

Comment: well, it would help you get around the issue wouldn't it?  you're also using a version that's 7 months out of date.  you might consider upgrading to the latest version, and if it persists, filing a bug report.